# Very big fee for token on testnet

Tags: solidity, testnets, tokens, gas-price, fees

I'm new here and try to make my own token. I kinda made it actually, but fee for it is very big(cheapest one is 0.65 eth). Here's my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a / b;
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) return;
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract MuviGen is owned {

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint public _totalSupply = 0;
    string public constant symbol = "MUVI";
    string public constant name = "Muvi";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    uint256 public constant RATE = 1000000000000000000000;
    uint256 public constant maxTokens = 1000000000000000000000000000;

    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) allowed;

    function () payable {
        createTokens();
    }

    function MuviGen() {
        balances[owner] = balances[owner].add(100000000000000000000000000);
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(100000000000000000000000000);
    }

    function createTokens() payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        uint256 tokens = msg.value.mul(RATE);
        require(_totalSupply.add(tokens) <= maxTokens);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    function totalSupply() constant returns(uint256 totalSupply) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns(uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns(bool success) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[msg.sender].add(_value);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns(bool success) {
        require(allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_from] >= _value && _value > 0);
        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_from].add(_value);
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns(bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns(uint256 remaining) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed __owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}
```

Can you please help an tell me what am I doing wrong? Maybe I need somehow change gas price or something like that? Tnx in advance

Comment: You have to do some work first, try reducing the contract to a smaller example to show the issue, or try in another testnet like rinkeby.io or a private testnet, to rule out some other condition in the network.